# How to download a file in Python?

Tags: python, download, python-requests, lib

So the issue I am having isn't that there is a link of a PDF on the web I am trying to scrape and download onto my PC (It doesn't end in .pdf). I have a download link that I want to activate, which would then lead me to download a PDF onto my computer. It looks like this:

https://***.com/files/4122109/download?download_frd=1&verifier=xxx

When I click the link, it verifies I am the user that I am, and then lets me download the file with the ID contained in the above query. The content-type for this file is "application/pdf" so I know it downloads a PDF file for me. I just need a library that "clicks" or "activates" the download for me.

Also, I am trying to do this for all the URLs I am pulling from a course on Canvas in a GET request. I am not trying to use Selenium here because I am getting these URLs from an API. Any advice in this approach would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a file over HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-to-download-a-file-over-http)

Comment: Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  instead.

Comment: Thanks! wget.download(url) library worked. @Flo